# prototype: show a element when scroll page pased 800px

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, domdocument

If user up, then hide the element. A div.

i have something:

```
<script>

window.onscroll = function()
{

        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 900 || self.pageYOffset > 900) {
            $('#divId').css('display','block');
        } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 900 || self.pageYOffset < 900) {
            $('#divId').css('display','none');
        }
}

</script>
```

But not work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $someDiv = $("#someDiv"),
        top = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (top > 200) {
        $someDiv.show();
    } else {
        $someDiv.hide();
    }
});​
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alextercete/ShPXJ/).